# [Junit-pioneer]How to add RetryingTest for all test methods?

Tags: junit5, retry-logic

I'd like to use `@RetryingTest(3)` for all my test methods, is there a easy way to apply it for all test methods instead of add `@RetryingTest(3)` for test method one by one? Or if there is a global way to enable retry for all test methods?

Walkthough docs:

- https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/retrying-test/
- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#advanced-topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (at least out of the box) since `@RetryingTest` is a [`@TestTemplate`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.10.0/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestTemplate.html):

> `@TestTemplate` is used to signal that the annotated method is a *test template* method.

Similar to [`@Test`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.10.0/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Test.html), it is designed to target only `ANNOTATION_TYPE` and `METHOD`. JUnit Jupiter had a [similar request](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1761#issuecomment-466149986) back in 2019 and they decided against a class-level `@Test` annotation:

> There are many ways to declare tests in Jupiter: `@Test`, `@TestFactory`, `@TestTemplate` (`@RepeatedTest`, `@ParameterizedTest`) -- we want them to be explicitly visible and not rely on a pattern that matches a method signature.

See also: https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer/issues/720